# Capturing a portion of the screen as fast as possible

Tags: c#, graphics, capture

I have made a tool which captures a portion of my screen.

[image]

All the pixels within that red square are loaded into a Bitmap:

```
private Bitmap Capture()
{
    var bitmap = new Bitmap(measurementToolBounds.Width, measurementToolBounds.Height);
    using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
    {
        g.CopyFromScreen(measurementToolBounds.Location, Point.Empty, measurementToolBounds.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
        g.Flush();
    }
    return bitmap;
}
```

Unfortunately, `CopyFromScreen` takes roughly 30ms to execute.

I've tried using `gdi32.dll` and `BitBlt`, too, but as far as I know, `CopyFromScreen` calls `BitBlt` behind the scenes.

Is there a faster way to do this using C# or perhaps even a 3rd party utility tool that you know of that I can use to retrieve a portion of the screen as a byte array?

Comment: What was the measured time when preparing everything and calling BitBlt by yourself?

Comment: Since you are concerned about 30ms I'm guessing you're doing this in a loop, recording or streaming. If so then open up Task Manager and find the gdi handles column and see if they have fixed the old bug where CopyFromScreen leaked a gdi handle on every call. If not then you should see a steady rise in used gdi handles for your process.

Comment: @MaxSenft Roughly the same ;(

Comment: true `CopyFromScreen` is not much more than a [managed wrapper](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/Graphics.cs,925) around `BitBlt`. you could optimize by including a rip-off of the framework implementation and obtaining the handles (DCs) just once.

Comment: Hmhm ... did you check out the info from https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dsui_team/2013/03/25/ways-to-capture-the-screen/ ?

Comment: I tested this with my code and with [ScreenToGif](https://github.com/NickeManarin/ScreenToGif/blob/df612eed127ce81a0123d2e3566c49ef71d1abe3/ScreenToGif/Util/Native.cs#L1502) code (quite basic, by the way, at least in this repository), calling `BitBlt` directly. The results are more or less the same (min 20-max 29 ms per capture, full screen). The `ScreenToGif` app can capture up to 60 FPS, though. Search the source code, maybe there's something about caching the unmodified parts. The .Net "translation" adds some overhead , anyway.

Comment: @Jimi Thanks, I will take a look at `ScreenToGif`.

Comment: @Jimi I just tried `ScreenToGif`. I was getting a frame every 30ms on average (according to the statistics tab). I did set it to 60FPS, though. Did you actually try it and if so, what was your FPS?

Comment: 25.5 to 27.5 FPS. With an average of min 20-max 29 ms per capture (unbiased), it was obvious that it could not get to 60 FPS. You could try with [System.Windows.Media.Imaging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.imaging?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Media.Imaging);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework&view=netframework-4.7.2)), which has an internal caching system. Otherwise, you'll have to find some other library that uses DirectX more, well, directly.

Comment: @Jimi Thanks for that. I am taking a look at Microsofts Desktop Duplication API source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/direct3ddxgi/desktop-dup-api#feedback It is in c++, though. Yikes.

Comment: That is more often used for transferring the screen over the network. And it's really hard to use (mostly, because very few are even aware of it's existence, so its hard to get some help/examples). You'ld probably be better off with the DirectX support of `System.Windows.Media`, which you also can use from WinForms.

Comment: @Jimi Right. Okay. Any chance you have a link to a bit of sample code or even an article to get me going? Thanks!

Comment: I'll see what I can do. Mind that `System.Windows.Media` is more often used for Presentation (obviously). But it has also a good renderer and great decoder/encoder classes. Not very often used, unless you have to capture the rendering of other WPF classes (like Windows Media Player, for example).

Comment: ~60 Hz limit suggest VSync ... also how big is the area you are capturing?

Comment: @Spektre The area is 100x100 pixels. I thought of vSync, but I'm not sure what to do about it: I am using a remote desktop (the tool runs on the remote desktop too), so there is no monitor connected per se (I just RDP into it). The VM is in Azure. Is this something I can disable?

Comment: @Spektre The area is 100x100 pixels. I thought of vSync, but I'm not sure what to do about it: I am using a remote desktop (the tool runs on the remote desktop too), so there is no monitor connected per se (I just RDP into it). The VM is in Azure. Is this something I can disable?

Comment: @pookie 100x100 pixels is very small area so it should be much faster. try 500*500 if the time will not change you are syncyng. For the sync you do not need a monitor ... Sync signal is generated by the graphic card. You can try to disable sync in driver ... but if the app or some stuff is forcing it you might be in bad luck

Comment: @Spektre Thanks, I'll check this out!